# How to get new RDD from PairRDD based on Key

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

In my Spark Application, I am using one `JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<Tuple3<String, String, String>>>` which has large amount of data.

And my requirement is that i need some other RDDs `JavaRDD<Tuple3<String, String, String>>` from that Large PairRDD based on keys.

Comment: Why not to just filter base rdd?

Comment: Use java.util.stream.Stream to filter the data.  Please have a look [link](http://www.journaldev.com/2389/java-8-features-for-developers-lambdas-functional-interface-stream-and-time-api#java-stream-api)

Comment: In PairRDD, I am using List that has millions of Tuple3<String, String, String>. But I only Need 50 Sorted Records from that list based on third argument of Tuple.
So for this, I am just thinking to create some new Rdds and than after sort there tuples.
If there is any other way, please tell me.

Comment: @PrakharAsthana thanks, But i am using Java 7, not Java 8. Is there any other way in Spark?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please also add an example of the current state and expected output. Right now it's not clear whether you want one element of the RDD or a merge of several.

Comment: @Prakhar, the question is about Apache Spark. Your link has no relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the Java API, but here's how you would do it in Scala (in `spark-shell`):

```
def rddByKey[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[(K, Seq[V])]) = {
  rdd.keys.distinct.collect.map {
    key => key -> rdd.filter(_._1 == key).values.flatMap(identity)
  }
}
```

You have to `filter` for each key and flatten the `List`s with `flatMap`.

I have to mention that this is not a useful operation. If you were able to  build the original RDD, that means each `List` is small enough to fit into memory. So I don't see why you would want to make them into RDDs.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question? Let me know.